# How to disable welcome page on JBoss EAP 7 Domain Cluster

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am new to working with JBoss and I'm working on setting up a cluster to test with. I followed the directions [from middleware](https://www.middlewarebox.com/2018/02/a-domain-controller-is-central-point.html) to setup a JBoss Domain cluster on a single Linux VM using JBoss EAP 7.1.6. I am now trying to deploy a web application to my cluster using the admin console to test that the cluster is working.

I have created a simple hello world web app using [liweinan's cluster demo source code](https://github.com/liweinan/cluster-demo) that should display the current time. I tested the app and it displays correctly on a standalone cluster, but when I test my domain cluster I am seeing the page telling me that I need to disable the welcome content. What am I doing wrong? Is there something that also needs to be configured on the slaves?

Here is my jboss-web.xml in my application war:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

In the host-master.xml the domain controller is:

```
    <domain-controller>
            <local/>
    </domain-controller>
```

In the domain.xml file I have updated the interfaces to match the address of my machine. I also commented out the welcome content in the undertow.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
    <buffer-cache name="default"/>
    <server name="default-server">
        <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
        <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
        <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            <!--<location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>-->
            <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
            <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </host>
    </server>
    <servlet-container name="default">
        <jsp-config/>
        <websockets/>
    </servlet-container>
    <handlers>
        <!--<file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>-->
    </handlers>
    <filters>
        <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="JBoss-EAP/7"/>
        <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

In both of the host-slave.xml files I have updated the socket interface management port, the interface inet-address, and added an offset for the servers.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I've been researching this for days without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue wasn't with my configuration. When you deploy the application you can't change the name. I was changing it from ClusterDemo.war to ClusterDemo. When I left the .war on the name, the app ran with no issues.